# Regular expression for currency data recognizing comma and decimals

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

Need currency post-processor to be used for all currency amounts. The logic for the post-processor should handle the following cases:

```
14.978.00 -> 14,978.00 

14.97800 -> 14,978.00 

14,97800 -> 14,978.00
```

Logic is as follows:

1. If the number is well formed (commas in correct place and at most one decimal point found with 2 digits after it)- then do nothing.
2. Else if a decimal point is found in a position where a comma would make sense, then change the decimal point to a comma 
   (change decimal to a comma if the decimal has 3 or more numbers to the right of it)
3. After doing step 2, Any number that ends in a comma followed by 5 digits (`,nnnnn`) should be converted to `,nnn.nn`.

Answer (score 0):

`s/\.(\d{3})/,$1/`
Match a point followed by 3 digits, replace that by a comma followed by those same 3 digits (which were captured).

`s/,(\d{3})(\d{2})$/,$1.$2/`
Match a comma, followed by 5 digits (a group of 3 and a group of 2) at the end of the string, replace that by a comma, the first 3 digits (which were captured), a point, and the last 2 digits (which were captured).

Comment: i have put ^([0-9]{2,3})\.([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})$|^([0-9]{2,3})\,([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})$|^([0-9]{2,3})\.([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})$     in regular expression and $1\,$2\.$3  in replacement, but it is just displaying ,. in output, it is not picking up the integer values

Comment: That would mean it is matching but not capturing, which is weird. However, that's not what I suggested _at all_.